# how can I configure cups to be used from network machines with windows?

Tags: debian, cups

I've been fighting with CUPS since many hours (too many) and I still cannot figure out what's wrong. I installed a printer on a Debian Machine, when I add a printer I have two options "Local printers" and appear the printer that is connected (the one I want to use to print from my network) and "Other network printers", so, I thought maybe I should add local printer and I chose my printer and I installed and all. It prints the tests and all, so, from Windows I added my printer with the url `http://192.168.1.2/printers/myprinter` but it doesn't work. I read more and I find out the IPP protocol, some use it but some use AppSocket/HP JetDirect. I am very confused; which is the way I should add this printer? Do I have to add a printer in the section of network printers?

I installed samba and I added this

```
<Location /printers>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow 192.168.0.*
  Allow 192.168.1.*
</Location>
```

When I add printers on Windows it asks for 3 options, first search (shows me computers on network, I can't choose the machine with Debian, it asks me to login. I don't know which user, it's not Debian's OS, nor Windows), second it's "selected shared printer", but I can not enter ipp:// , it only accepts http:// , and third one is printer through TPC/IP, there I can add http:// ipp:// or socket:// but none of them are successful.

Comment: If you are printing to a CUPS server, it will be the ipp:// protocol. Port 631 by default.

Comment: thank you, I tried but it cant be recognized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to make sure that you add the `Listen :<port>` to your cups configuration file `/etc/cups/cups.conf`.

#### /etc/cups/cups.conf

```
# Our private connection we listen to 
Listen *:12345
# The port number her just an example
# Substitute it with one you wish to use.

# Allow machines on local network to use printers
<Location /printers>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow 192.168.0.*
  Allow 192.168.1.*
</Location>
```

*If* this is what your configuration already looks like then **awesome**. Once you've saved `/etc/cups/cups.conf` make sure to **restart** the `cups` server to apply the changes. If your system is using **systemd** as its `init` this can be done with `systemctl restart cups.service`. If it's using `sysvinit` then `/etc/init.d/cups restart` would be used.

Once this is setup go to each windows machine and install a `network printer` and use the following scheme to identify the printer.

`http://<cups_server_hostname>:12345/printers/<printer_name>`

When asked what driver that you would like to use. Select the `Generic` category and use the one labeled **MS Publisher Color Printer**. Finish the installation of the network printer, test.